# very large memory allocation in 64-bit linux

Tags: memory, 64-bit, malloc, calloc

I am trying to allocate a single very large piece of memory (>2.5gb) on a centos 64-bit linux. The hardware has more than 16gb physical memory. However, when I use malloc or calloc, they return null. The code runs in root account, and as far as I checked with ulimit there is no limit on memory allocation. What can be the problem ?

Thanks.

Mete

Comment: You have a 64-bit program, right?

Comment: what's the largest piece of memory you can allocate?

Comment: I guess. I am compiling with icc (intel c compiler) and using intel64  environment variables. I guess it compiles to 64-bit, how can I check this ?

Comment: Run `file` against the executable.

Comment: I tried both 10GB and 2.5GB, and both fails.

Comment: file displays me following: reorder: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped

Comment: have you tried setting the heap in ld? `-Wl,--heap,2147483648`

Comment: Please also post complete source code.

Comment: I did not get setting --heap argument. Is it an argument of icc ?

Comment: the source code is very simple, just trying to populate a huge matrix which is minimum 2.5GB.

Comment: If it's simple, then please post it. There might be a mistake in it that you fail to recognize.

Comment: ok it seems I try to reserve more somewhere else and it lefts me with less than 2.5GB. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Google the sbrk routine, it will help you.

Comment: I did but doesnt malloc do everything needed ? Should I think about calling sbrk myself ?

Comment: No, malloc should be fine. All in all, as you can see, people all think it ought to work the way you described it. Given that it doesn't work, there must be something you haven't told us (such as a bug in the code).